# Sorting coordinates of point cloud in accordance with X, Y or Z value

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, sorting

`A` is a series of points coordinates in 3D (X,Y,Z), for instance:

`>> A = [1 2 0;3 4 7;5 6 9;9 0 5;7 8 4]`

`A =
     1     2     0
     3     4     7
     5     6     9
     9     0     5
     7     8     4`

I would like to sort the matrix with respect to `"Y" (second column)` values.

Here is the code that I am using:

`>> tic;[~, loc] = sort(A(:,2));
    SortedA = A(loc,:)
    toc;`

`SortedA =
     9     0     5
     1     2     0
     3     4     7
     5     6     9
     7     8     4`

`Elapsed time is **0.001525** seconds.`

However, it can be very slow for a large set of data. I would appreciate it if anyone knows a more efficient approach.

Comment: If you have a decent GPU, you can harness really good speedup with it, just some info.

Comment: @Divakar Does it need to change any setting in my computer?

Comment: You only need to use `gpuArray` with the PCT toolbox, but do you have a decent GPU to work with?

Comment: @Divakar Yes buddy, I got "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 645" which should be fine. Right?

Comment: Added a [GPU based solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26772776/3293881), see how it works out at your end!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introductory Discussion

This answer would mainly talk about how one can harness a compute efficient `GPU` for solving the stated problem. The solution code to the stated problem presented in the question was -

```
[~, loc] = sort(A(:,2));
SortedA = A(loc,:);
```

There are essentially two parts to it -

1. Select the second column, sort them and get the sorted indices.
2. Index into the rows of input matrix with the sorted indices.

Now, `Part 1` is compute intensive, which could be ported onto `GPU`, but `Part 2` being an indexing work, could be done on `CPU` itself.

### Proposed solution

So, considering all these, an efficient `GPU` solution would be -

```
gA = gpuArray(A(:,2)); %// Port only the second column of input matrix to GPU
[~, gloc] = sort(gA); %// compute sorted indices on GPU
SortedA = A(gather(gloc),:); %// get the sorted indices back to CPU with `gather` 
                             %// and then use them to get sorted A
```

### Benchmarking

Presented next is the benchmark code to compare the `GPU` version against the original solution, however do keep in mind that since we are running the `GPU` codes on different hardware as compared to the originally stated solution that runs on `CPU`, the benchmark results might vary from system to system.

Here's the benchmark code -

```
N = 3000000; %// datasize (number of rows in input)
A = rand(N,3); %// generate random large input

disp('------------------ With original solution on CPU')
tic
[~, loc] = sort(A(:,2));
SortedA = A(loc,:);
toc, clear SortedA loc

disp('------------------ With proposed solution on GPU')
tic
gA = gpuArray(A(:,2));
[~, gloc] = sort(gA);
SortedA = A(gather(gloc),:);
toc
```

Here are the benchmark results -

```
------------------ With original solution on CPU
Elapsed time is 0.795616 seconds.
------------------ With proposed solution on GPU
Elapsed time is 0.465643 seconds.
```

So, if you have a decent enough `GPU`, it's high time to try out `GPU` for sorting related problem and more so with MATLAB providing such easy `GPU` porting solutions.

---

### System Configuration

```
MATLAB Version: 8.3.0.532 (R2014a)
Operating System: Windows 7
RAM: 3GB
CPU Model: Intel® Pentium® Processor E5400 (2M Cache, 2.70 GHz)
GPU Model: GTX 750Ti 2GB
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `sortrows`, specifying column 2:

```
Asorted = sortrows(A,2)
```

Simpler, but actually slower now that I test it...  Apparently `sortrows` is not so great if you're only considering 1 column to sort. It's probably best when you consider multiple columns in a certain order.

Comment: Thanks, it looks useful. But, I would leave the question open with hope of getting a faster solution.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB does have a feature called `sortrows()` to do this but in my experience, it tends to be as slow as what you're doing for a general unstructured matrix.

Test:

```
N = 1e4;
A = rand(N,N);
tic;[~, loc] = sort(A(:,2));
SortedA = A(loc,:);
toc;

tic; sortrows(A,2); toc;
```

Gives:

```
Elapsed time is 0.515903 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.525725 seconds.
```

Comment: I see an even larger difference.  Apparently `sortrows` is not so great if you're only considering 1 column to sort.  It's probably best when you consider multiple columns in a certain order.

Comment: @chappjc, Interesting. I just read the source code for it and it turns out that sortrows calls a C wrapper only if the column dimension is more than 4. Otherwise, it just does what OP does.

Comment: In R2014 it's more than 3 (`sortrowsc`), otherwise it calls `sortrows>sort_back_to_front`, which does just as the OP does, like you said. I doubt there's a faster way than what he's doing... it's the standard way for a reason.  :)